# Lodash. Smart merge two objects by keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the two objects. A and B.

A

```
{
   "beta" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "hamma" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "zerta" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "mozes" : 5
}
```

B

```
{
   "beta" : 5,
   "hamma" : 2
}
```

How do I can loop through the A keys, compare it with the B object and update the values of the existing keys in the A object via Lodash? Maybe there is exists some nice way? I tried to use "assing, assignWith" but looks like I haven't understood how it works.

The result should looks like that:

```
{
   "beta" : {
     "value": 5,
     "error" : null
   },
   "hamma" : {
     "value": 2,
     "error" : null
   },
   "zerta" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "mozes" : 5
}
```

Thanks for any information.

I have resolved this solution via native js by that way but I want to know how can I do it via Lodash.

```
export function mapServerModelToStateValues(state, serverModel) {
    let updatedState = {};
    const serverModelKeyList = Object.keys(serverModel);

    Object.keys(state).forEach(stateKey => {

        serverModelKeyList.forEach(modelKey => {
            if ( modelKey === stateKey ) {
                updatedState[ stateKey ] = {
                    ...state[ stateKey ],
                    value : serverModel[ modelKey ]
                }
            }
        });
    });

    console.log(updatedState);
}
```

Comment: You know Lodash is completely written in JS? If you can do it with vanilla JS, why bother introducing another library to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I know, obviously. But I want to know how to resolve this task by Lodash using.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `_.mergeWith` lodash method and pass custom function.

```js
var a = {"beta":{"value":null,"error":null},"hamma":{"value":null,"error":null},"zerta":{"value":null,"error":null},"mozes":5}

var b = {"beta":5,"hamma":2, "mozes": 123}

_.mergeWith(a, b, function(aValue, bValue) {
  _.isPlainObject(aValue) ? aValue.value = bValue : aValue = bValue
  return aValue
})

console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if `b` contains a "mozes" key?

Comment: Very nice though I feel that ternary might trip up some linters :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that iterates over the B array and uses [**set**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) to update the value:

```
_.each(updates, (value, key) => _.set(data, `${key}.value`, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, notice that the result will have all the keys in the same `value, error` format

```js
const A = {
  "beta": {
    "value": null,
    "error": null
  },
  "hamma": {
    "value": null,
    "error": null
  },
  "zerta": {
    "value": null,
    "error": null
  },
  "mozes": 5
}
const B = {
  "beta": 5,
  "hamma": 2
}

const C = _.mapValues(A, (value, key) => {
  return {
    ...value,
    value: B[key] || value.value
  }
});

console.log(C)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Love this one but what happens if the `B` value is *falsy* (like `0`)

Comment: you can always refine the condition `B[key] || value.value` depending on your use case - do you support falsy values?

Comment: I'd go with a `hasOwnProperty` check instead

Comment: this doesn't work.  when run it sets mozes.value to undefined even though it's set to 5 in the source object.

Answer (score 0):

Map through the `_keys` from your second object to update the first object accordingly:

```js
// obj a
const a = {
  beta: {
    value: null,
    error: null
  },
  hamma: {
    value: null,
    error: null
  },
  zerta: {
    value: null,
    error: null
  },
  mozes: 5
};

// obj b
const b = {
  beta: 5,
  hamma: 2
};

// map through the 'obj b' keys and update 'obj a' accordingly
_.keys(b).map(key => {
  a[key].value = b[key];
});


// log obj a to the console
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Update:** I would use the solution from @GruffBunny - the idea is similar to this one, but done much more elegantly using lodash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) and [`lodash#mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) to achieve this.

```
var result = _.merge({}, a, _.mapValues(b, value => ({ value })));
```

```js
var a = {
   "beta" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "hamma" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "zerta" : {
     "value": null,
     "error" : null
   },
   "mozes" : 5
};

var b = {
   "beta" : 5,
   "hamma" : 2
};

var result = _.merge({}, a, _.mapValues(b, value => ({ value })));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```